# Webpack-dev-server with client and server bundling

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm developing a React app with server side rendering, and I'm bundling both server and client code, but I can't make webpack-dev-server to work with the following configuration.

This is the structure of my app:

```
.
├── dist
│   ├── assets
│   │   ├── bundle.js
│   │   ├── index.css
│   │   └── index.html
│   └── server.js
├── package.json
├── src
│   ├── client
│   │   ├── App.js
│   │   ├── components
│   │   ├── css
│   │   ├── index.html
│   │   ├── index.js
│   │   ├── libs
│   │   └── main.less
│   └── server
│       ├── App.js
│       ├── bin
│       ├── routes
│       └── views
└── webpack.config.js
```

The idea is that Webpack compiles the code from `/src/client/app.js` and bundle it into `/dist/assets/bundle.js`; Webpack also compiles the code form the server in `/src/server/app.js` and bundle it into `/dist/server.js`.

In `package.json` I have this scripts:

```
"start": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
"server": "node ./dist/server.js",
"client": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open",
"dev": "webpack --mode development --watch",
"build": "webpack --mode production"
```

And also a proxy to:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:4000"
```

So every request to the API will go to this port, which is where my server is. In my `/src/server/app.js` I set the public files like this:

```
app.use(express.static('dist'));
```

And in my webpack conf I have this:

Requires:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals'); // Remove node_modules when creating the bundle
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
var config = require('./config.test.json');
```

This bundles the server:

```
module.exports = [

    {
        entry: './src/server/App.js',
        output: {
            filename: 'server.js',
            path: __dirname + '/dist',
            libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
        },
        target: 'node',
        node: { console: false, global: false, process: false, Buffer: false, __filename: false, __dirname: false, },
        externals: nodeExternals(),
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    exclude: [/node_modules/, /\.less$/, /\.css$/],
                    use: {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                    },
                },
                { test: /\.json$/, },
                { test: /\.css$/, use: { loader: 'ignore-loader', }, },
                { test: /\.less$/, use: { loader: 'ignore-loader', },
                },
            ],
        },
    },
```

And this bundle the client

```
    {
        entry: './src/client/index.js',
        output: {
            filename: 'bundle.js',
            path: __dirname + '/dist/assets',
        },
        devServer: { port: 3000, },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: { loader: 'babel-loader', },
                },
                {
                    test: /\.html$/,
                    use: [ { loader: 'html-loader', options: { minimize: true }, }, ],
                },
                {
                    test: /\.less$/,
                    use: [
                        { loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader },
                        { loader: 'css-loader',
                            options: { modules: true, importLoaders: 1, localIdentName: '[name]-[hash:4]', sourceMap: true, minimize: true, }, },
                        { loader: 'less-loader' },
                    ],
                },
            ],
        },
        plugins: [
            new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist/'], { watch: true }),
            new HtmlWebPackPlugin({ template: './src/client/index.html', filename: './index.html', }),
            new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: 'index.css', chunkFilename: 'index.css',
            }),
        ],
    },
];
```

Now, If I do `npm run build` and `npm run server` I will have the site rendering from backend from `localhost:3000`, serving JSON requests from `localhost:4000/users`, for example. But if I do `npm run start` I can't make it work. Does anyone has any idea how to set the `webpack-dev-server` in this situation?

Comment: Where is the problem? client-side or server-side?

Comment: Hm the problem is about how to configure webpack-dev-server to work with the server part as well. For now, if I set it for the client, it works; but as the server is being bundled with the React components, the hot module replacement doesn't work for it. So I need to set the webpack-dev-server with the server part as well, but I don't know how to do it…

Comment: You can try on your devServer object by adding `historyApiFallback: true`

Comment: To make it work with your backend, you don't use webpack-dev-server. You need to use the webpack-dev-middleware in your express js server.  https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware

Comment: Hi @Daniel, thank you! Is there any reason for that?